# it was like a fibonacci I can't figure out the code for this

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Scanner wew = new Scanner(System.in);
        int b = 0;
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a number of row:");
        b=wew.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a number of range:");
        i=wew.nextInt();    

        for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++)
        {
            for (int g = 1; g <= i; g++){

                System.out.println(g+"");
            }
            for ( int g = c-1; g >= 1; g--)
            {
                System.out.println(g+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

The code is still out of my knowledge. It was like a fibonacci and I know my output went too far from the expected results

Expected results:

```
Please enter a number range: 4
Please enter a number rows: 4

1111 2111 3111 4111
1211 1311 1411 1511
1131 1141 1151 1161
1114 1115 1116 1117
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. Also it is not clear what exactly tje code should do as also in the picture it is not consistent (number of rows = 3 but prints 4)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer *"(number of rows = 3 but prints 4)"* I think that's the question

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the picture shows how it should be. I ran the code and the output is very far off

Comment: It should be like this,


Please enter a number range: 4
Please enter a number rows: 4

1111 2111 3111 4111
1211 1311 1411 1511
1131 1141 1151 1161
1114 1115 1116 1117

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you're right of course

Comment: @Xiaomy please include that comment properly formatted in your question

Comment: @Xiaomy ok, but what's the meaning of those numbers? And why such an odd output, as XtremeBaumer asked?

Comment: It was a given task to me then I can't figure out how to code it.

Comment: then you should probably add *what* was asked (to the question, please)

Comment: I'm so sorry, i forget the question. but can you focus on the output, as you can see on the picture  the inputed 2 range should be 4 and the 3 range should be 4 then thats the output on the picture.

Comment: @Xiaomy ok, but if we don't know *what* the program is supposed to do, even if the input were correct we couldn't still help you.

Comment: Just to make sure you get the messages: A) **never** include screen shots or heck pictures of screens in questions. Text is text, and should be added as well formatted text to questions B) when you are asked to add missing information, please **edit** the question. Nobody wants to dig through 10, 15 comments to figure relevant details.

Comment: I'm so sorry. just delete my non sense post. thankyou for advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the Kotlin code which does what you want (it was easier for me to develop it this way):

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = Scanner(System.`in`)

    print("Please enter a number range: ")
    val numOfCols = input.nextInt()

    print("Please enter a number of rows: ")
    val numOfRows = input.nextInt()

    for (i in 1..numOfRows) {
        for (j in 1..numOfCols){
            for (k in 1..numOfCols){
                if (k == i) {
                    print(k+j-1)
                } else {
                    print(1)
                }
            }
            print(" ")
        }
        println("")
    }
}
```

and this is the Java equivalent:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a number range: ");
        int numOfCols = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter a number of rows: ");
        int numOfRows = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <=numOfRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= numOfCols; j++){
                for (int k = 1; k <= numOfCols; k++){
                    if (k == i) {
                        System.out.print(k+j-1);
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(1);
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. I really appreciate it alot! Thankyou so much Sir!

Comment: How Sir? Sorry newbie here.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there should be check mark button near the top of the answer.